# How can I approximate a deli kaiser roll?

Tags: baking, rolls

I want to approximate kaiser rolls, as you would buy in a deli or bodega. I tried [this recipe](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/kaiser-rolls-recipe), and the results were tasty, but not really a kaiser roll. Specifically, they were:

- Too dense
- Not crusty enough

How can I get closer to the target?

## Update

Some photos of what I'm trying to achieve are [here](https://notalkxjusteat.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/1-hard-roll.jpg), [here](http://www.sweetblogomine.com/.a/6a00d8341ce95e53ef017ee3d0cb13970d-pi), and [here](https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-kaiser-roll-with-poppy-seed-81304105.jpg).

Comment: I don't know if your *kaiser rolls* are supposed to resemble the German *Kaiser Brötchen*, but the picture shown with that recipe definitely shows a different bread structure. Which makes me wonder what outcome you want? Can you add a picture?

Comment: @JanDoggen Done. I've never been to Germany and have never eaten a Kaiser Brötchen, but the photos I found on Google look similar.

Comment: I have never baked them but have looked up some German recipes. They differ a lot, but two things seem worth trying: Let the yeast grow in lukewarm milk for at least 15 minutes; and let the dough portions rest 15 minutes before making the rolls.

Answer (score 1):

**Density**

A high-protein bread flour will give strength to the roll, and allow it to rise higher. While it should still have some chew to it, this may be what your perceiving when you refer to density. Think of the difference between a pizza (typically high-protein, or "bread" flour) and a muffin or pastry (often uses lower protein flour). Bread flour can be substituted 1:1 with AP flour.

**Crustiness**

Instead of milk, try using an egg wash. This can be done by mixing a lightly beaten egg with 1 tbsp of water and a pinch of salt. Brush the rolls just before sprinkling on the poppy seeds.

Some more sugar might also improve browning. You could try increasing the sugar content by about 50% and see what effect it has on your rolls.

---

If you're interested in learning more about bread baking, this answer is based on a recipe from Bread Illustrated from America's Test Kitchen. I am not affiliated with them, but I feel like I should give the credit where it's due.

The techniques for making bread can get very complicated and precise, so there may be other ways to improve your rolls. I would also recommend a recipe that uses weight instead of volume for measuring flour/water ratios. Hydration levels in your dough can cause a significant difference in your final product.